# How can I replace a character in every table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to replace a single character in each column of every table of the database; however, I don't want to do it table-by-table.
Is there a way to do the whole thing in one attempt?

Comment: In every table and each column?

Comment: Or in every table name?

Comment: In every table and each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming only text values will be modified, you can do something like below.

```
IF(NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables where name = 'TEMPQUERYTABLE' and type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'))
BEGIN
    SELECT T.name AS Table_Name ,
           C.name AS Column_Name ,
           P.name AS Data_Type ,
           P.max_length AS Size ,
           CAST(P.precision AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(P.scale AS VARCHAR) AS Precision_Scale
           INTO TEMPQUERYTABLE
    FROM   sys.objects AS T
           JOIN sys.columns AS C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
           JOIN sys.types AS P ON C.system_type_id = P.system_type_id
    WHERE  T.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' AND P.name in ('nvarchar','varchar') AND T.name <> 'TEMPQUERYTABLE'
END

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Old_value VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @New_value VARCHAR(10)
SET @Old_value = 'xx'
SET @New_value = 'yy'
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'UPDATE ' + Table_Name + ' SET ' + Column_Name + ' = REPLACE(' + Column_Name + ',' + @Old_value +','+ @New_value + ')' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM TEMPQUERYTABLE

EXEC(@SQL)

--DROP TABLE TEMPQUERYTABLE
```

But I'm curious to know why you need such thing done in the first place.

Comment: The problem is that there are two characters which look the same, but have different ASCII codes. This causes problems in some situations, such as searching. Now the problem has been solved, thanks to you.

Comment: Some of the strings have been trimmed after running this query. Do you know which part causes it?

Comment: I highly doubt this query trims the values. Did it trim all columns or only a few? What were the characters you used to replace?

Comment: No, only a few columns, and they also have been trimmed in different indexes; for example one has been trimmed on the 1000th character and the other 1100th.
There is this character in Persian "ی", which people usually use an Arabic character "ي" instead, due to the wrong keyboard choice. This causes all the problems.